# Check which files a program uses

Tags: windows-xp

Is there any application that will check which files a running program reads, modifies etc. and can present me with a list of these?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: XP, sorry forgot to mention

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, look at two Sysinternals tools (since acquired by Microsoft):

- [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx): what file handles are in use at any given time.

> If [ProcessExplorer] is in
>   handle mode you'll see the handles
>   that the process selected in the top
>   window has opened; if Process Explorer
>   is in DLL mode you'll see the DLLs and
>   memory-mapped files that the process
>   has loaded.

- [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx): trace all file system accesses by a process (or path, or...)

> Process Monitor is an advanced
>   monitoring tool for Windows that shows
>   real-time file system, Registry and
>   process/thread activity.

- [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) is another Sysinternals tool, similar to Process Explorer in that it lists a processes file handles, but it's a console app, as opposed to the other two.

Comment: can they be used programmatically?

Comment: @Geo: no, they can't.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Geo - see my edit - you could use `handle` programmatically, if you wished.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what OS you're using, but BSD-like OS's such as Mac OS X have [fs_usage](http://man.cx/fs_usage(1)).

Answer (score 1):

On unix platforms you can use `lsof | grep <pid>  OR lsof -p <pid>` to view all files open by a particular process.However it does not list you which files are being read or written.
However a script can be made to compute checksums of the files to find out if it is being written or not.

Comment: oops just saw u meant on windoze!